# how to set default value to a relation in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

Hi i am using MYSQL and Hibernate and have a table Customer with column customer_type with default value 1,    its foreign key in Customer but primary key in CustomerType table find the below code In my Customer hbm file i have written the below code:

```
<many-to-one name="customerType" class="CustomerType" lazy="false">
    <column name="customer_type_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

But the column is not null and in my table its default value is 1. and i am not setting this object while saving my Customer object becos default value is there in table but getting exception propertyviolationexception not null references null value how can i come over this problem and how to set default value to a relation in hibernate

Answer (score 0):

```
As per SQL default value will be set when you omit the column in insert script.
```

It works the same way with Hibernate as well, which ultimately executes insert script by including columns as per mapping in HBM. One approach is to create an object for `CustomerType` with your default values. Then set the same to your parent object while you are saving parent object if that is not set by any of your business logic. So, that get saved without any exception.

Other simple approach is in many-to-one mapping set `insert='false'` and map a primitive type field for column customer_type_id and set value to `1`. So, this one would get saved to DB for your default value column, when retrieving the relation will get loaded happily.

Comment: Hi Pokuri, thank u for your valuable suggestion its works fine i know the first approach and dont know the second one thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You force your field `customer_type_id` to be **not-null**, so hibernate initialize the value with its lowest value. If you want to preset your id with a default value, use the code below in your hibernate mapping for class `CustomerType`:

```
<propery name="customerTypeId" type="long" column="customer_type_id">
    <column=" name="customer_type_id" not-null="true" default="1000"/>
</property>
```